# How do I use preg_match to extract part of a found string?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string, such as `"https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/artpop/id687591810?ign-mpt=uo%3D4"` from which I want to extract just `687591810`.

My regex skills are not great, but I can use `/id\d{4,12}` to at least get the right block (it gives me `/id687591810`). I'm wondering if there's a way using `preg_match` to search for the pattern but then return just the bit I want in one go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [capturing group](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php):

```
$url = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/artpop/id687591810?ign-mpt=uo%3D4";
preg_match('#/id(\d{4,12})#', $url, $output);
echo($output[1]);
```

output:

```
687591810
```